# Basic Iphone App need code looked over

Tags: iphone, xcode

Im trying to make basic Iphone app

Needs to be able to do the following

- Display a phrase across the screen
- Phrase needs to change at midnight every night to new phrase
- From a list of phrases
- When the application is turned off or suspended the phrases still need to move to the next one within the 24 hour time.

I have been trying different combinations of the code and got nothing from it, I am quite new to most of this but thought I understood it better, maybe its the xcode thats throwing me off.

```
UILabel *scoreLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];

scoreLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];

[self addSubview:scoreLabel];

scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", score];

NSTimeInterval secondPassed = [[NSdate date] timeInervalSinceReferenceDate];

Int dayNumber = secondPassed /60 /60 /24;

Int phraseNumber = dayNumber % [phrases count]:
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

here is sample of the code I have been throwing around If anyone can help me bring it together a bit more that would help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't describe what it does and doesn't do, I can only suggest the following:

1 - cut the app down to the bare minimum to be sure that it performs it base functionality (display a message)
2 - ditch the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate and instead look for the date changing.  
     to check that the date has changed, save the current date in a preferences file and every X intervals retrieve the date from the system, comparing that date to the stored value.

Comment: So with linning it up what is an example on how I should cut it down? Again The the only thing I want it to do is display a phrase, then change the phrase every 24 hours while retainning the information when it is turned off to keep moving through the list of other phrases every 24 hours.

Comment: Please describe first what is and isn't working - otherwise the advice you get will just be generic suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I am quite new to this a younger student just starting to learn, I am wondering If I am using the right code for my program, and if its in the right position, but it dosent seem to work on my system when trying to get it running. My question is what do I need to change, or what does it need to look like to get going. Basically need an example of the correct outlay of the code.

Comment: since you say you're a beginner, I'll point you to http://www.aaronspjut.com/mind/index.php/2009/02/06/iphone-hello-world-in-3-lines/  Once that part works, then you can work on the timer specific areas that you need.

Comment: A better solution though is to go through the basics @ developer.apple.com - they give some very detailed information as you get further into the process - and their sample code is very good too